# ProfileService In Roblox Studio doesn't work

Tags: roblox

I was developing the PlayerData of my roblox simulator game using the ProfileService library from _G.Madwork

It doesn't load the profiles correctly

This is the main Data script:

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ServerScriptService = game:GetService("ServerScriptService")

local Template = require(ServerScriptService.PlayerData.Template)
local Manager = require(ServerScriptService.PlayerData.Manager)
local ProfileService = require(ServerScriptService.Libs.ProfileService)

local ProfileStore = ProfileService.GetProfileStore("Production", Template)

local KICK_MESSAGE = "An error occured while joining the game, please retry"

local function CreateLeaderstats(player)
    local profile = Manager.Profiles[player]
    if not profile then return end
    
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    
    local coins = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    coins.Name = "Coins"
    coins.Value = 0
    local gems = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    gems.Name = "Gems"
    gems.Value = 0
end
    
    
local function LoadProfile(player: Player)
    local profile = ProfileStore:LoadProfileAsync("Player_" ..player.UserId)
    if not profile then
        player:Kick(KICK_MESSAGE)
        return
    end 
    
    profile:AddUserId(player.UserId)
    profile:Reconcile()
    profile:ListenToRelease(function()
        Manager.Profiles[player] = nil
        player:Kick(KICK_MESSAGE)
    end)
    
    if player:IsDescendantOf(Players) == true then
        Manager.Profiles[player] = profile
        CreateLeaderstats(player)
    else
        profile:Release()
    end
    
end

for _, player in Players:GetPlayers() do
    task.spawn(LoadProfile, player)
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(LoadProfile)
Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local profile = Manager.Profiles[player]
    if profile then
        profile:Release()
    end
end)
```

And this is the Template MuduleScript:

```
local Template = {
    Coins = 0,
    Gems = 0
}

return Template
```

This is the Manager ModuleScript:

```
local Manager = {}
Manager.Profiles = {}
return Manager
```

....................................................

Comment: Have you enabled [Datastores in Studio](https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/data/data-stores)?

Comment: Yes, I had. They are activated